# overlapping div layout with grid 960

Tags: css, grid

I´m using the 960 css grid files for a web layout and it works great, but for this layout I need to overlap the divs.

And if I have 2 columns side by side I can overlap the left one by setting class="pull_1" on the right one.

```
<div class="grid_2">
    <p>
     <img src="../star.jpg" width="236" height="329" style="float:left;">
    </p>
  </div>

<div class="grid_2 pull_1">
    <p>
     <img src="../star.jpg" width="236" height="329" style="float:left;">
    </p>
  </div>
```

But if I want to overlap upwards? Yes I can set margin-top:-50px; and that will overlap
both to the left and upwards.

```
<div class="grid_2">
    <p>
     <img src="../star.jpg" width="236" height="329" style="float:left;">
    </p>
  </div>

<div class="grid_2 pull_1" style="margin-top:-50px;">
    <p>
     <img src="../star.jpg" width="236" height="329" style="float:left;">
    </p>
  </div>
```

I want to great a layout like this and I just wonder if this is the way to do it or if anybody has some better way to do it?
[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you give all of your divs a CSS rule of: `position:absolute`, you can then set `top` and `left` position offsets to create a layout like the one in the photo you posted. Make sure the divs are ordered from back to front if you want the get the layering correct..

Here's a very simple example of what you could do with `absolute` positioning:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZqRgj/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kyle, Yes I have tryd that and it work good, and after some more thought I would like to make it dynamic, getting the images from the db and then maybe, randomize the position in some clever way, any thoughts? Setting a css class on every 1,15,30 image, and another class on every 2,14,29 and so on!?

Comment: if you want each image in a different position, the css rules wouldn't have to be in classes. you could use inline css instead:
`<div style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:20px"></div>`
You could use jquery to randomly generate the top and left values when a div is added to the page.